# Using Validation.HasError to override Tooltip template

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

Everywhere I've looked, I've found the standard solution to attach a ToolTip to a control whose Binding has `Validation.HasError == true` but nowhere shows how you might completely override the ToolTip's template so that you could, for example, still have your own custom theme which overrides the style for all ToolTips but when a control has that specific condition you can specify a template which has a red border, red see-through background and red text, for example.

The standard solution is:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Does anyone know how to expand this to set the ToolTip background, border and text colour without overriding the base ToolTip control style? Bear in mind I've already specified this to create my own "theme" so I don't want to change it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" Style="{StaticResource MyInheritedStyleForValidation}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Where `MyInheritedStyleForValidation` should probably override your theme style.

Comment: Almost there. It's showing the styled ToolTip but the content is wrong (blank) - I suspect a `{RelativeSource FindAncestor}` may be needed rather `{RelativeSource Self}`

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked that part. FindAncestor might do the trick!

Comment: Hmmmm. No luck so far. Tried `AncestorLevel=1` and `AncestorLevel=2`.

Comment: If you run the code in debug mode, what System.Windows.Data errors do you get in the output? That might give a hint as to where the problems is. Maybe it's trying to get the validation errors of the ToolTip.

Comment: It's not throwing any errors because the Binding appears to be valid (i.e. ToolTip has a Validations.Errors collection there's just nothing set to CurrentItem so Content is blank). Other ancestor controls also have this collection, as well so it's a bit like shooting in the dark...

Comment: Any luck to the tool tip content ? Facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've settled for not changing the style.

Answer (score 2):

Set the DataContext of the ToolTip to the parent control:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ToolTip Foreground="White"
                         Background="Black"
                         DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                         Content="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix the tooltip content.

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding GeneralTooltip}"/>
       <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"/>            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ToolTip  Style="{StaticResource WarningTooltip}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Style>
```

The tooltip template from his style:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">                      
                                    <!--Display the text-->
                                    <Label Background="Transparent" 
                                         BorderThickness="0" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         Grid.Column="1"                                            
                                         Content="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=2}}"                                            
                                         BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```